# Nested async.eachSeries in waterfall executes in wrong order

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, request, waterfall

In second function in the async waterfall, the `eachSeries` callback (`urlCallback`) in my code executes after the waterfall callback (`waterfallCallback`), for reasons I cannot suss out.

```
   async.waterfall([
      function(callback) {
        request(website, function (error, response, html) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
              pageUrls = getPageUrls(html)
              callback(null, pageUrls)
            }
          })
      },
      function (pageUrls, waterfallCallback) {
          async.eachSeries(pageUrls, function (url, urlCallback) {
              console.log('SET ' + url)
              request(url, function (err, response, body) {
                  var $ = cheerio.load(body)
                  $('#div').children().each(function(){
                    console.log($(this).children("a").attr("href"));
                    itemUrl = $(this).children("a").attr("href")
                    itemUrls.push(itemUrl)
                  })
                  urlCallback(null,itemUrls)
              })
          },
          waterfallCallback(null, itemUrls))
      }
    ],
      function(err, results) {
        console.log("results: " + results)
    })
```

AFAIK, the async.eachSeries takes three arguments (array,functionToBeExecuteOnEachItem,callback) and execute them in that order. Somehow not here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters for `async.eachSeries` are function definitions. Something like `waterfallCallback` or `function(err,result){}`.

When you call `waterfallCallback(null, itemUrls)`, that is not a function definition, that is running the function itself!

Changing to simply `waterfallCallback` should do the trick.

Update: Also, `.eachSeries` does not return the values as an array, its final callback is just `function(err)`. Checkout `.mapSeries` [link](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.mapSeries) instead, which will return the resulting array in the final callback `function(err,finalArray)`. (Be aware that each return of a `.map` will be an element in the array, so if you return an array, you'll get data structures like `[ [], [], [] ]`)

Comment: Very helpful. However, it seems like `urlCallback(null,itemUrls)` does not return the array as desired.

Comment: Does `urlCallback` not return the specified array in the `eachSeries` callback?